# quickblox user signup and verification

Tags: quickblox, email-verification

Is there a way to verify a user via the email address provided when they sign up using the Quickblox iOS SDK? If not, what would be the best way to verify the user using Quickblox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickBlox doesn't provide this feature out of the box cause of complexity for end users.

Let's imagine this situation:

- User registers in iOS app
- After this he should open his email and verify email address. It's a bit annoying, isn't?

You can verify user by **QBUUser lastRequestAt** field http://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/Classes/QBUUser.html#//api/name/lastRequestAt

After Sign Up - **lastRequestAt** field will be null. Only after real user login it will equal activity datetime

Comment: Thanks! Quick follow up. I couldn't use QuickBlox for our user database since the client wanted an email dropped in the new users inbox when they register and hit the verify button, so we had to depend on other services, but still using QuickBlox for chat. Since QuickBlox would need a user to sign in for chat, I have paired `externalUserId` for easy sign-in. My question is, how would I go about resetting the password in the QB database after it has been reset in ours? There's no way for me to get the old password and update it, or login with the new one.

Comment: yes, just do [QBUser updateUser:...] and provide password and oldPassword. More info here  https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/blob/master/snippets/QB_SDK_Snippets/UsersModuleViewController.m

Comment: @IgorKhomenko For uploading avatar during registration, user is required to 1-sign up 2-login 3-update blob. 2 is not possible because pending email verification. How should this be handled?

Answer (score 1):

You can authenticate your users either by login or by email. Check details [here](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Signing_Up) .

Comment: What I meant by that was how can I tell Quickblox to send an email to the newly signed up user for verification. Just like how you can send an email using the SDK for the password to be reset